# Not able to click an element as other element obscures it

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

```
my question is : I am using selenium with python,I have a button to be clicked but i'm unable to click that element . as the script gives me error that<br>
```

Message: Element  is not clickable at point (633,740) because another element  obscures it
Below is the HTML code

```
<div class="split" align="center">
   <button class="button primary" type="submit" id="submitbtn">Next</button>
 </div>

And my script is 

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".page-loader") 
#this is the page loader that i am trying to block because this obscures my element that i have to click
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", element)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
signup = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".register #submitbtn")))
#.register is the class of the form under which this button is present and #submitbtn is the id of that button

signup.click()
```